# Semi-sandwich complex IUPAC name

Tags: nomenclature, aromatic-compounds, coordination-compounds, carbonyl-complexes

[image: Unknown Compound]

I've tried looking [here](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/ebook/978-0-85404-182-4#!divbookcontent), but I can't figure it out.

As a start, what is just the cobalt and cyclopentadienyl anion compound called.
How does that name get added to the trimethylphosphine and carbonyl groups.

I want to ask further questions about this compound on chemistry stack exchange, and I think it would be a good idea to be able to use the name in those questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of this compound is **carbonyl(η<sup>5</sup>-cyclopentadienyl)(trimethylphosphane)cobalt**. Note that, generally, the prefixes denoting the organic groups and any other ligands are placed in alphabetical order before the name of the metal.

The current version of [*Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (Red Book)*](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf) presents the rules for formulating and naming coordination compounds (Chapter 9) and organometallic compounds (Chapter 10). An abridged version is included in the IUPAC Technical Report [Brief guide to the nomenclature of inorganic chemistry. *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2015,** *87*(9–10), 1039–1049](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/pac-2014-0718) as well as in the corresponding four-sided lift-out document, which is available as [supplementary material](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2015.87.issue-9-10/pac-2014-0718/suppl/pac-2014-0718_Suppl.pdf).

In particular, the ‘η<sup>5</sup>-cyclopentadienyl’ term used here is explained in Section IR-10.2.5.1. as follows:

> The special nature of the bonding of unsaturated hydrocarbons to metals via their π-electrons has led to the development of the ‘hapto’ nomenclature to designate unambiguously the unique bonding modes of the compounds so formed. (…) The Greek symbol η (eta) provides a topological description by indicating the connectivity between the ligand and the central atom. The number of contiguous atoms in the ligand coordinated to the metal is indicated by a right superscript numeral, e.g. η<sup>3</sup> (‘eta three’ or ‘trihapto’), η<sup>4</sup> (‘eta four’ or ‘tetrahapto’), η<sup>5</sup> (‘eta five’ or ‘pentahapto’), etc. The symbol η is added as a prefix to the ligand name, or to that portion of the ligand name most appropriate to indicate the connectivity, (…)
>
> The ligand name η<sup>5</sup>-cyclopentadienyl, although strictly speaking ambiguous, is acceptable as a short form of η<sup>5</sup>-cyclopenta-2,4-dien-1-yl, due to common usage.
>
> These ligand names are enclosed in parentheses in the full name of a complex. Note the importance of making rigorous use of enclosing marks, etc. to distinguish the above bonding modes from the other four cases below. (…)